# asmack + android + chat application

Tags: android, chat, asmack

I have succesfully implemented a chatting activity within my android application. That activity can send and receive messages. But when the user is on other activity he can't receive messages. Is there a easy way to make all the activities able to receive messages without re writing message recieve code on each and every activity????

Answer (score 0):

Implement Messagelistener in your chatting activity

Answer (score 0):

Move your Message listener code into a Service.